# How do I stop flask app from running while I am using a recursive function?

Tags: python, flask

I want to recieve some data from user and then use web scraping. The problem arises when user submits the information that the app keeps on loading which is understandable as I have used a recursive function before returning rendered template.

I need to know what can be done to just recieve data provided and the stop the app such that the recursive function keep running and do the web scraping as desired. TIA

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

headers = {
    "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36'}

link = ""


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    global link
    if request.method == "POST":
        link = request.form["link"]
        mail = request.form["mail"]
        print(link, mail)
        scrap_price(9999999)

    return render_template('index.html')


def scrap_price(previous_price):
    global link
    page = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()
    price = float(price[2:])
    
    if price < previous_price:
        print('reduction')
    
    previous_price = price
    
    scrap_price(previous_price)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, threaded=True)
```

Comment: You mean index.html is being returned before scrap_price has run? I don't think that should be happening regardless of whether scrap_price is recursive. What exactly are you observing?

Comment: if you have long-running code (not only recursion) then you should run it in separated `thread` or `process`. On Django popular method is to run separated program like `Celery` and send information to this program (using queue or database) and it will run this procces. I think in Flask documentation should be also example for `Celery`

Comment: Flask doc: [Celery Background Tasks](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/celery/)

Comment: @SimonN   The statement: return render_template(index.html) doesn't get executed since it goes in my recursive function (scrap_price). I want to return index.html and then go to the function.

Comment: @furas is it not possible to do without this?

Comment: you can't run code after `return` which sends HTML to client. You have to run scraper in separated thread - and then it can send `return ...`.

Comment: So basically I move scraper to a knew thread by celery and let other code run as usual?